# Put a pie chart in a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to make my android widget to display a pie chart.
I know I can create a pie chart using:
`PieChartView pieChartView = findViewById(R.id.pieChart);`

But **I'm not able to use `findViewById()` for widgets**.

**Edit:**

The error says "Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(?)'"

This is what I've tried so far:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

        PieChartView pieChartView = findViewById(R.id.pieChart);  //error occurs here

        List<SliceValue> pieData = new ArrayList<>();

        pieData.add(new SliceValue(25, Color.GREEN).setLabel("1"));
        pieData.add(new SliceValue(25, Color.RED).setLabel("2"));
        pieData.add(new SliceValue(25, Color.BLUE).setLabel("3"));

        PieChartData pieChartData = new PieChartData(pieData);

        pieChartData.setHasLabels(true).setValueLabelTextSize(14);

        pieChartView.setPieChartData(pieChartData);  //have not been able to create a PieChartView object so can't do this line

        pieChartData.setAxisXBottom(new Axis());
        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

But I'm not able to use findByView(), so I have not been able to create a PieChartView object and thus have not been able to set the pie chart data with setPieChartData().

Comment: Please share more of your code or what you tried, is there an error? findViewById() returns null? what kind of error/difficulty are you facing?

Comment: `findViewById()` works inside `onCreateViewMethod()`. That is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the layout using `RemoteViews`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews

It should be possible to do something like this:

```
val view = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.my_widget)

view.pieChart [do your magic]
```

Comment: It's giving an error saying "cannot resolve symbol 'pieChart'"